# Why does this String.equals() method always return false?

Tags: java, android, string

I have a class for which I have implemented a custom hashCode() and equals(Object) method using the Eclipse method generator. Each object of the class has a String field called `mUid` which should be unique and is enough to determine equality. The overridden methods look like this:

```
    @Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((mUid == null) ? 0 : mUid.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    DataSource other = (DataSource) obj;
    if (mUid == null) {
        if (other.mUid != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!mUid.equals(other.mUid))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

But for some reason, when I compare two objects of my class, it always returns false. I've stepped through the code with a debugger and can determine that the mUid strings are the same. But my `equals(Object)` method always returns false at the line

`if (!mUid.equals(other.mUid)) {return false;}`.

This means the String equals() method is saying the strings are not equal. But, in the debugger I can see that even their hashcodes are equal.

Here is a debugging screenshot:
[image: Debugging screenshot]
Can anyone please explain what is happening?
Thanks.

### Update: It works!

I should point out that I am not calling the equals(...) method directly, but rather from `List<DataSource> list.contains(DataSource)`. It turns out that if I step through the `equals(Object)` code, it shows me that it returns false for comparing every object in the list (even if there is a match). But it seems the `List.contains()` method returns the right value (true or false) anyway. Don't know why this is, but it works. I had an extra semicolon after the `if(list.contains(dataSource));` so I could not rightly see that `contains()` was working fine. **Thanks for your help everyone**.

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but `this == obj` will only be true if both sides are the very same instance.

Comment: mUid and other.mUid are string variable..?

Comment: @Cobra_Fast that check is just a short circuit for when `obj` is the very same instance... You may notice it doesn't return false if the comparison fails and there are about 10 more lines of code after that?

Comment: yes @CapDroid, both are string variables

Comment: Please give a sample showing the problem. We have no idea whether they really *are* equal strings.

Comment: The code looks ok. Can you stop you debugger on the line comparing equality of the strings and post the content of both? Check also the length in the debugger for the case you overlooked some whitespace character for example.

Comment: My guess would be whitespace in the `mUid` strings.  If you put a breakpoint on the line after the cast and put a watch on `mUid.equals(other.mUid)` does that return true or false?

Comment: Some information is missing because you say the strings are equal and the equals method returns false!!! please show us also the declaration of mUid...

Comment: Not that it would solve the problem, but I'd just return mUid.equals(other.Uid). The if is superfluous and a bit confusing to read because of the negated condition.

Comment: I've added a screenshot taken during debugging!

Comment: This question is interresting as nobody seems to figure why it return false.

Comment: I still don't know why it returns false, but my ultimate goal is still achieved (see question update). Thanks for your help all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method should work. I just tested with this code and it worked fine:

```
public class DataSource {

    private String mUid;

    public DataSource(String m) {
        mUid = m;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((mUid == null) ? 0 : mUid.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        DataSource other = (DataSource) obj;
        if (mUid == null) {
            if (other.mUid != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!mUid.equals(other.mUid))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        DataSource ds1 = new DataSource("test");
        DataSource ds2 = new DataSource("test");
        System.out.println(ds1.equals(ds2));
    }

}
```

The console output was "true";
When I changed the code to `DataSource ds2 = new DataSource("test1");` it returned "false";

Comment: Thanks. I was making a small example. But I figured in order to simulate my actual environment, it has to be run on an Android environment. Although I would expect it to work no matter the JVM in use.

Comment: Yeah, there definitely shouldn't be a difference there. Is it possible for you to provide the actual strings (copy/paste - not retyping manually) which you are putting into mUid?

Comment: You are right, it does seem to work. See my update in the question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`This means the String equals() method is saying the strings are not equal. But, in the debugger I can see that even their hashcodes are equal.`

Equal hashcodes do not necessarily represent equal strings. Are their contents really equal?

Comment: yes, even the case is the same. I know the hashcode is no guarantee but I just checked it for double insurance. I trimmed all whitespace and everything. From what I can see in the debugger, the strings are equal character for character.

Comment: So if you are stopped in the debugged and add a watch to those two equal Strings this.mUid.equals(other.mUid), what does it give?

Comment: If `mUid` really are `String` instances, false being returned would indicate that both differ somehow.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 if (mUid == null)
{
    if (other.mUid != null)
        return false;
} 
else if (!mUid.equalsIgnoreCase(other.mUid))
    return false;
return true;
```

Comment: What makes you think the OP *wants* case-insensitive equality? Note that this breaks the hashCode() implementation, as two equal instances could have non-equal hash codes.

Comment: WHy do you think his ids are case insensitive?

Comment: That doesn't work either, I've tried. Besides, different case means different `mUid`. I also figured the eclipse generator would produce code which would not need editing.

Answer (score 0):

If you used the Eclipse generator this is very strange, and hand editing the generated code should not be necessary. Can you post the whole class source code? Do you extend another objects?

Comment: No, I do not extend any other objects, I did not post the whole code because I didn't want the question to be too long. But it is just a simple java class with a bunch of string fields alongside their getters and setters.

Comment: Then it is indeed very strange... What is the content of the strings? Perhaps it is a encoding or whitespace problem, like newline characters, tabs character etc?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I taken a look at a decompiled version of String.equals:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj)
{
    if(this == obj)
        return true;
    if(obj instanceof String)
    {
        String s = (String)obj;
        int i = count;
        if(i == s.count)
        {
            char ac[] = value;
            char ac1[] = s.value;
            int j = offset;
            int k = s.offset;
            while(i-- != 0) 
                if(ac[j++] != ac1[k++])
                    return false;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

So in the debbuger, I would try to compare and print the 2 char Arrays. You can use the toCharArray method for this. If the char indeed differs, it is likely to be an encoding problem and I'd try to check the encoding used by Yahoo and ensure you decode using it.